# V8 crash when test infinite-recursion js in CentOS6.3 x86-64

Tags: crash, stack-overflow, v8

V8 will crash when run infinite-recursion js in Centos6.3 x86-64. But it don't crash in Centos5.7 x86-64 using the same case. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. Centos6.3 is different from Centos5.7 in stack_initializing, that cause setting v8 contraint failture. The root reasion is that code for setting contraint is not totally correct.